# Where can I find a light ball for Pikachu?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I would like to use a Pikachu on my team, but without a light ball it doesn't compare very well to a Raichu. Is there anyway to get one in Pokemon X and Y?

Comment: The pikachu I caught had one already. So you could just thief on every pikachu you find.

Comment: Oh, hmm do we have data on the chances of them carrying one? That would be a good answer for the question if you wanted to give it a shot. Well, so would your comment but with the % chance it would be an answer I could mark as accepted.

Comment: I don't know the % if I did I would have answered :(

Comment: In previous generations starting from Emerald on up, it was only a 5% chance to find a Pikachu holding a light ball. Not sure if that changed in generation 6. I know when I was fishing for luvdisc to get heart scales, I got one pretty much every time, and the chance for that item in prior games was 50%.

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention, if you have a Pokemon with the "compound eyes" ability at the front of your lineup, it will increase the chance of the wild pokemon holding an item. Thus slightly increasing the chance of a pikachu holding a light ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Serebii.net](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/lightball.shtml) Pikachu has a 5% chance to hold a light ball (the same as Black 2/White 2).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Catch a caterpie and evolve it to butterfree, once you have compound eyes it should be relatively easier to find a lightball since your chances increase 50% I suggest catching the pickachu since I'm not sure if fainting it with thief will get you it's item

Answer (score 3):

In Santalune Forest, you can find wild Pikachu.  In B/W, it is a 1% chance to catch one carrying a Light Ball, but in B/W2, it is 5%.  So in X/Y, it is probably 5% as well. If the lead of the party has the ability compound eyes, it increases the chance for the Pikachu to be holding the light ball.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to do some testing out in the field with a Vivillion (Compound Eyes) and Shuppet (Frisk, Thief):

> Route 3: Encounter rate too low for workable results
>
> Santalune Forest: 1 Light Ball / 10 Pikachu
>
> Friend Safari: 3 Light Balls / 20 Pikachu

Accounting for slight variations, we can assume a 10% chance that a Pikachu holds a Light Ball, although this is accounting for Compound Eyes.

Answer (score 0):

For me to get a Pikachu, I just use a pokeradar and if i find a pikachu i use butterfrees compoundeyes to increase the rarity of the light ball and then i use my eevees Covet to faint the Pikachu and walk away holding a light ball. Unfortunately, it hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score -2):

You could always just use a pokemon as bait, so that when you find a Pikachu, if it does a lot of damage, it will probably be holding a light ball!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! You are answering a question which already has an accepted answer as well as several other answers and is a couple months old. Usually, this is unhelpful but ff you think your answer is substantively different from other answers--that it gives a new answer to the question--then answering is a good thing! I suggest using the 'Unanswered' tab at the top of the page to find questions that are more current than this one.